# Facebook API Graph feed topic

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanna use facebook graph , to get all the posts from the group with their messages, pictures and so on.
I have managed to do the all above, but now i am facing another problem , i want to get all the group posts by their topic(tags) and i don’t know how.

Basically my intention is to filter and arrange group posts by their topics(tags) .
I have tried and looked everywhere on developer.facebook.com but i can’t find any solutions or at least a sign that can help me.

Can anyone help me with that and show where i can read or at least to give me an example that could help me to work out what to do next.

I don’t need a fully working code just to understand if it is possible to get the group posts tags or not, and if yes where i can read more about this. Thx

Comment: you will need to do that on your own, after getting all posts.

Comment: Yes i understand that, but how can i retrieve posts tags(topics) from facebook group.       What i am doing now is “  /group-id/ feed?fields=id,message,picture  “    but i also need this edge(key)  for tags(topics) , i have trying all of them and didn’t find the right one.

Comment: what makes you believe there is an api for it? what do the docs tell you?

Comment: Docs does tell/show anything about this, i can get comments, likes  and so on but not tags.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how can i achieve that, without to do it manually?

Comment: if there is nothing about it in the docs, there is no way. it is as simple as that.

Comment: yeah i see, i actually found on stackoverflow few posts with questions same to mine. At the moment is not possible to do it :(

Comment: Anyway thx for your help @luschn